# RSpec model test testing encrypted attribute randomly failing with "key_derivation_salt is not configured"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, rspec, github-actions, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 7.0.3 app with a model that has an **encrypted attribute**. I have an RSpec test which tests the model's behaviour. I have a GitHub Actions workflow setup running RSpec. *However*: **every first run for a specific commit fails, every next run succeeds**. As

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Configuration:
       key_derivation_salt is not configured. Please configure it via credential active_record_encryption.key_derivation_salt or by setting config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt
```

The GitHub actions config (non-essential details left out for brevity):

```yaml
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  rspec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: ".ruby-version"
    - name: Bundle Install
      run: |
        gem install bundler -v $(grep 'BUNDLED WITH' -A1 Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1 )
        bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
        bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
    - env:
        RAILS_MASTER_KEY: "${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}"
      run: RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
```

I have the secret setup in the repo configuration:

[image]

The necessary encryption configuration is stored in `test.enc.yml`:

```yaml
active_record_encryption:
  primary_key: u▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉
  deterministic_key: 4▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉
  key_derivation_salt: R▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉
```

I really dislike the idea of using some flavour of RSpec retry/rerun gem to fix it. I'd really like to solve the underlying issue. Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 5):

it looks more like a issue with loading your `credentials` in test environment. I've stumbled upon similar error today, but I don't want to pass `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` for test environment. What I did were adding this code to `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```rb
config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = 'test'
config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = 'test'
config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = 'test'
```

Unless you don't need an exteremly secure DB in a test environment this should do the job for you.